# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio error at startup

Tags: sql-server, configuration, ssms, startup-error

I get this error when I try to run Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio:

> The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.

[image: error window image]

SxSTrace detail:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwWd5.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFlYe.jpg)

What I did for solving the problem:

- reinstalled SQL Server
- reinstalled Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
- updated at recent version of .NET Framework
- reinstalled Visual C++ Redistributable

And I still get that same error.

What should I do?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this BUG?

Comment: @MiscellaneousUser I did not.

Comment: After a couple of attempts, i got working.  When you say 'Reinstalled' Studio, do you mean repair or uninstall/install?

Comment: @MiscellaneousUser I know that I uninstalled and than installed the latest version of it. Can you explain how did you do to get it working? Maybe your answer will be useful for others.

Comment: I can not even reinstall. The installation window runs forever. By forever I mean more than 24 hours.

Answer (score 5):

you should install an earlier version. I had the same error and I installed version 18.5 and it worked just fine.

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#185

Answer (score 4):

Uninstalling did not work.

Upgrading (Installing newer version or same version) did not work.

What worked:

1. delete or rename “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18”
2. delete registry manually or via .reg file

   reg DELETE “HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio” /reg:32)

Afterwards, installing SSMS worked without a flaw and it started.

Found at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/7ab37d2b-6bac-4221-b827-d274b00b9a56/ssms-18-how-to-uninstall?forum=sqlkjmanageability&prof=required, similar to https://superuser.com/a/1440276/146668 .

Comment: This also worked for SSMS 19

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error with version 18.9.2. I don't know if it's related to the problem, but I firstly installed SSMS in `Program Files` and not in `Program Files (x86)`.

First I have tried to repair the installation, with no success.

Then I have uninstalled SSMS, rebooted by PC, re-installed SSMS (this time in the default `Program Files (x86)` folder) and rebooted my PC again.
After these steps, I was able to start SSMS without errors.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following to solve this error.

Copied all the files and folders from the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\ from a working machine and pasted on the server which was having issue.

Once the copying was completed, I it started appearing in Add or remove programs @ control panel.

Post copy SSMS started working normally.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the following Sql related ones from the control panel.

[image]

Then i followed these steps

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66085979/16391774

I reinstalled the same version (at present latest version v18.12.1 and i used it version) and my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by having the application repair itself.

1. Click to **Search**
2. Enter **Add or remove programs**
3. Find application
4. Click on it and click **Uninstall** that appears
5. Click **Repair**