# Re-solve how to install SSMS

Tags: windows, installation, ssms

When I used to install SSMS I used to get "Loading packages. Please wait...". But their is no use of it still it's going like that all the time but not loaded any packages.
Can anyone will help. How to install SSMS.

Comment: please add some more details

Answer (score 41):

to fix this problem:

- remove temp files from %temp% folder (C:\Users<user name>\AppData\Local\Temp)
- open the register and remove "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio" or execute via cmd (with admin rights):

  reg DELETE “HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio” /reg:32
- run install with admin rights

Comment: Just for those who don't know register just open CMD as an administrator and run the command  => reg DELETE “HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio” /reg:32. It will ask for confirmation enter Yes and the operation should complete successfully.

Comment: Worked like a charm and thanks Wajid for the addition tip on the cmd prompt

Comment: It took me a few hours to find this solution, but I'm glad I did. It's the only thing that worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Fix this problem :

- Delete temp file, run cmd then enter: `%temp%`
- Open register and delete `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`
- Run install ssms with administrator permission
  ^^

Answer (score 0):

The new version 18 is only for 32 bit system. So if your system is 64 bit then download and install Azure Data Studio. It supports cross platform and can be used for Windows 32/64, Mac etc. [Download from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15)